# Find all solutions to $x^3-x^2+2x-2=0 \pmod {11}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

I get that $11$ is a small number and that I could maybe do this by inspection, but I was wondering if there was a more intelligent approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x^3-x^2+2x-2\equiv0 \pmod {11}$$

$$(x^2+2)(x-1)\equiv0\pmod{11}$$

Since $11$ is prime,

$$x-1\equiv 0\pmod{11}\implies x\equiv 1 \pmod{11}$$

OR

$$x^2\equiv-2\pmod{11}$$

Can you finish the last conrguence by yourself?

Comment: For the last congruence: 3 and -3. Why do you say "since 11 is prime", what if it wasn't?

Comment: @TMatija suppose $ab$ is divisible by $10$. Does that mean either $a$ or $b$ is divisible by $10$? Maybe, one is divisible by 2 and the other by 5?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: you could try to factor
$$\begin{align}
x^2(x-1) + 2(x-1) &= 0 \pmod{11}\\
(x^2 +2)(x-1) &= 0 \pmod{11}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Just hover your mouse over the "answered just now". You literally beat me by $1$ second. Cheers

Comment: @Sabyasachi: Wow, I am usually so slow. You answer is longer though.

Comment: Yes it is. It is basically the same, you should add $\pmod{11}$ though. (Yes I know, the modulo is present in the question, but someone in a hurry might misinterpret)

Comment: @Sabyasachi: Ok, I will do that...

Comment: Yeah it's all good now. Upvoted.